# Vincenty's distance Direct formulae numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, coordinate-system, geospatial

I've refactored a function from the `pygc` library used to generate the `great_circle`. The [Vincenty's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) below can be found [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html).

Destination given distance & bearing from start point (direct solution)
Again, this presents Vincenty’s formulæ arranged to be close to how they are used in the script.

$$
\begin{align}
a, b =&\ \textrm{major & minor semi-axes of the ellipsoid} \\
f =&\ \textrm{flattening }(a−b)\ /\ a \\
φ_1, φ_2 =&\ \textrm{geodetic latitude} \\
L =&\ \textrm{difference in longitude} \\
s =&\ \textrm{length of the geodesic along the surface of the ellipsoid (in the same units as }a \textrm{ & } b \textrm{)} \\
α1, α2 =&\ \textrm{azimuths of the geodesic (initial/final bearing)} \\
\\
\tan U_1 =&\ (1−f) \cdot \tan φ_1   &\textrm{(U is ‘reduced latitude’)} \\
\cos U_1 =&\ 1 / \sqrt{1 + \tan^2 U_1},\qquad \sin U_1 = \tan U_1 \cdot \cos U_1 &\textrm{(trig identities; §6)} \\
\sigma_1 =&\ \arctan(\tan U_1 / \cos \alpha_1) \\
\sin α =&\ \cos U_1 \cdot \sin α_1  &(2) \\
\cos^2 α =&\ 1 − \sin^2 α   &\textrm{(trig identity; §6)} \\
u^2 =&\ \cos^2 α \cdot \frac{a^2−b^2}{b^2} \\  
A =&\ 1 + \frac{u^2}{16384} \cdot \left\{4096 + u^2 \cdot [−768 + u^2 · (320 − 175 \cdot u^2)]\right\}  & (3) \\ 
B =&\ u^2/1024 \cdot \left\{256 + u^2 · [−128 + u^2 · (74 − 47 · u^2)]\right\} & (4) \\
σ =&\ \frac{s}{b \cdot A} & \textrm{(first approximation)} \\
\end{align} \\
$$

iterate until change in σ is negligible (e.g. 10<sup>-12</sup> ≈ 0.006mm) {
$$
\begin{align}
\cos 2σ_m =&\ \cos(2σ_1 + σ)    & (5)  \\
Δσ =&\ B \cdot \sin σ \cdot \left\{\cos 2σ_m + B/4 · [\cos σ · (−1 + 2 \cdot \cos^2 2σ_m)  \\
    − B/6 \cdot \cos 2σ_m · (−3 + 4 \cdot \sin^2 σ) · (−3 + 4 · cos² 2σ_m)]\right\} & (6)  \\
σʹ =&\ s / b·A + Δσ & (7) \\
\end{align}
$$
}
$$
\begin{align}
φ_2 =&\ \arctan(\sin U_1 \cdot \cos σ + \cos U_1 \cdot \sin σ \cdot \cos α_1  \\
    &\ / (1−f) \cdot \sqrt{\sin^2 α + (\sin U_1 \cdot \sin σ − \cos U_1 \cdot \cos σ · \cos α_1)^2})    & (8) \\
λ =&\ \arctan(\sin σ · \sin α_1 / \cos U_1 · \cos σ − \sin U_1 · \sin σ \cdot \cos α_1) & (9)  \\
C =&\ f/16 \cdot \cos^2 α · [4 + f · (4 − 3 \cdot \cos^2 α)]    & (10) \\
L =&\ λ − (1−C) \cdot f \cdot \sin α · \left\{σ + C \cdot \sin σ \cdot [\cos 2σ_m + C · \cos σ · (−1 + 2 \cdot \cos^2 2σ_m)]\right\}    & (11) \\
λ_2 =&\ λ_1 + L  \\
α_2 =&\ \arctan\left( \frac{\sin α}{−(\sin U_1 · \sin σ − \cos U_1 · \cos σ \cdot \cos α_1)}\right)     & (12) \\
\end{align}
$$

Where:

- \$φ_2, λ_2\$ is destination point
- \$α_2\$ is final bearing (in direction \$p_1 \rightarrow p_2\$)

### constants and imports

```py
"""Vincenty'distance Direct formulae"""
from typing import Tuple
from numpy import (
    vectorize,
    arctan,
    arctan2,
    tan,
    sin,
    cos,
    sqrt,
    pi
)
# a: Semi-major axis = 6 378 137.0  metres
A = 6_378_137.0
# b: Semi-minor axis ≈ 6 356 752.314 245    metres
B = 6_356_752.314_245
# f = flattening (a−b)/a
F = (A - B) / A
# (a²−b²)/b² ( lat reduction )
F2 = (pow(A, 2) - pow(B, 2)) / pow(B, 2)

TWO_PI = 2.0 * pi
```

### function

```py
upsilon2: Callable[[float], Tuple[float, float]] = (lambda u2: (
    # A = 1 + u²/16384 · {4096 + u² · [−768 + u² · (320 − 175 · u²)]}
    (1 + (u2 / 16384) * (4096 + u2 * (-768 + u2 * (320 - 175 * u2)))),
    # B = u²/1024 · {256 + u² · [−128 + u² · (74 − 47 · u²)]}
    ((u2 / 1024) * (256 + u2 * (-128 + u2 * (74 - 47 * u2))))
))


def vincenty_direct(
        latitude: float,
        longitude: float,
        azimuth: float,
        distance: float) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    """
    Returns: lat and long of projected point
    """

    azimuth = azimuth + TWO_PI if azimuth < 0.0 else(
        azimuth - TWO_PI if azimuth > TWO_PI else azimuth
    )
    # tan U1 = (1−f) · tan φ1
    tan_u1 = (1 - F) * tan(latitude)
    # cos U1 = 1 / √1 + tan² U1, sin U1 = tan U1 · cos U1
    cos_u1 = arctan(tan_u1)
    # σ1 = atan(tan U1 / cos α1)
    sigma1 = arctan2(tan_u1, cos(azimuth))
    # sin α = cos U1 · sin α1
    sin_alpha = cos(cos_u1) * sin(azimuth)
    # cos² α = 1 − sin² α
    cos2_alpha = 1 - pow(sin_alpha, 2)
    (
        # A = 1 + u²/16384 · {4096 + u² · [−768 + u² · (320 − 175 · u²)]}
        alpha,
        # B = u²/1024 · {256 + u² · [−128 + u² · (74 − 47 · u²)]}   (4)
        beta
        # u² = cos² α · (a²−b²)/b²
    ) = upsilon2(cos2_alpha * F2)

    def sigma_recursion(sigma_0: float) -> Tuple[float, float]:
        # cos 2σm = cos(2σ1 + σ)
        cos_2sigma_m: float = cos(2 * sigma1 + sigma_0)
        # Δσ = B · sin σ · {cos 2σm + B/4 · [cos σ · (−1 + 2 · cos² 2σm)
        # − B/6 · cos 2σm · (−3 + 4 · sin² σ) · (−3 + 4 · cos² 2σm)]}
        delta_sigma: float = (
            # B · sin σ ·
            beta * sin(sigma_0) *
            # cos 2σm + B/4 ·
            (cos_2sigma_m + (beta / 4) *
             # [cos σ ·
             (cos(sigma_0) *
              #  (−1 + 2 · cos² 2σm) -
              (-1 + 2 * pow(cos_2sigma_m, 2) -
               #   − B/6 · cos 2σm ·
               (beta / 6) * cos_2sigma_m *
               # (−3 + 4 · sin² σ) ·
               (-3 + 4 * pow(sin(sigma_0), 2)) *
               # (−3 + 4 · cos² 2σm)]
               (-3 + 4 * pow(cos_2sigma_m, 2)))
              )
             ))
        # σʹ = s / b·A + Δσ
        sigma = (distance / (B * alpha)) + delta_sigma
        # iterate until change in σ is negligible (e.g. 10-12 ≈ 0.006mm)
        if abs((sigma_0 - sigma) / sigma) > 1.0e-9:
            sigma_recursion(sigma)
        return sigma, cos_2sigma_m

    sigma, cos_2sigma_m = sigma_recursion(
        # σ = s / (b·A) (first approximation)
        (distance / (B * alpha)))

    # φ2 = atan(sin U1 · cos σ + cos U1 · sin σ · cos α1 /
    latitude = arctan2(
        (sin(cos_u1) * cos(sigma) + cos(cos_u1) * sin(sigma) * cos(azimuth)),
        # (1−f) · √sin² α + (sin U1 · sin σ − cos U1 · cos σ · cos α1)² )
        ((1 - F) * sqrt(pow(sin_alpha, 2) +
         pow(sin(cos_u1) * sin(sigma) - cos(cos_u1) * cos(sigma) * cos(azimuth), 2)))
    )

    def omega():
        # λ = atan(sin σ · sin α1 / cos U1 · cos σ − sin U1 · sin σ · cos α1)
        _lambda = arctan2(
            (sin(sigma) * sin(azimuth)),
            (cos(cos_u1) * cos(sigma) - sin(cos_u1) * sin(sigma) * cos(azimuth))
        )
        # C = f/16 · cos² α · [4 + f · (4 − 3 · cos² α)]
        c_sigma = (
            (F / 16) * cos2_alpha *
            (4 + F * (4 - 3 * cos2_alpha))
        )
        # L = λ − (1−C) · f · sin α · {σ + C · sin σ · [cos 2σm + C · cos σ · (−1 + 2 · cos² 2σm)]}
        return (
            _lambda - (1 - c_sigma) * F * sin_alpha * (
                sigma + c_sigma * sin(sigma) * (
                    cos_2sigma_m + c_sigma *
                    cos(sigma) * (-1 + 2 * pow(cos_2sigma_m, 2))
                )))
        # return longitude + omega

    return latitude, longitude + omega()


direct = vectorize(vincenty_direct)
```

### usage

```
import numpy as np
from vincenty import direct

def dev_dist(project_seconds=np.array([900, 1800, 2700, 3600])):
    """dev"""
    # position
    latitude = 33.01
    longitude = -98.94
    # direction
    azimuth = -171.95
    # speed
    meters_per_second = 11
    # distance projection
    distance = meters_per_second*project_seconds
    # in rads
    rad_lat, rad_lon, rad_azi = np.deg2rad((latitude, longitude, azimuth))
    # 
    degs = np.around(np.rad2deg(
        direct(rad_lat, rad_lon, rad_azi, distance)), decimals=2)

    points = np.swapaxes(degs, 0, 1)

    times = [f"+{x:02.0f}min"for x in project_seconds/60]

    projection = dict(zip(times, points.tolist()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dev_dist()
```

```
distance (meters)
>>> [ 9900 19800 29700 39600]
degs 
>>> [[ 32.92  32.83  32.74  32.66]
     [-98.95 -98.97 -98.98 -99.  ]]
points
>>> [[ 32.92 -98.95]
     [ 32.83 -98.97]
     [ 32.74 -98.98]
     [ 32.66 -99.  ]]
projection
>>> {'+15min': [32.92, -98.95], '+30min': [32.83, -98.97], '+45min': [32.74, -98.98], '+60min': [32.66, -99.0]}
```

Comment: What realistic number of `project_seconds` will you use - above 4?

Comment: 6 at the most. At a 15 min intervals out to +1:30. The data is available on a ~2min interval.

Comment: So then why all of the effort to use vectorised Numpy?

Comment: I see your point in the class I am developing this method for I am passing pandas series as lat,lon,azi and the offset

Comment: https://github.com/leaver2000/probtrack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a great idea to `from numpy import`, since there are so many symbols needed that that can lead to significant namespace pollution. The typical approach is just `import numpy as np`.

Rather than `pow(, 2)` you can just `**2`.

`upsilon2` should not be a lambda, and should be a regular function instead.

The angle normalisation of

```py
    azimuth = azimuth + TWO_PI if azimuth < 0.0 else(
        azimuth - TWO_PI if azimuth > TWO_PI else azimuth
    )
```

is not necessary, and even if it were, you should just do

```
azimuth = np.mod(azimuth, TWO_PI)
```

Don't recurse! Python has a very shallow stack capacity and no tail optimization. Just iterate - and this is quite easy with your existing function.

Your indentation sometimes deviates from 4 spaces. Try to keep this consistent.

Rather than `_lambda`, to escape a keyword it's more frequent to see `lambda_`.

Don't `vectorize(vincenty_direct)`. You can write an *actual* vectorised implementation with very little modification to your original implementation.

Add some tests. The only ones that I have shown are to test against regression.

Don't `np.around`. Keep full precision. There are better ways to truncate precision for print if that's what you're looking for.

Your use of `.swapaxes` can be replaced with `.T`.

You would benefit from being a little more granular with your functions, cutting them out of closure scope to make dependencies more explicit. Other benefits are that profiling - if that ever becomes necessary - is much easier.

### Suggested

```py
"""Vincenty's distance Direct formulae"""
from pprint import pprint
import numpy as np

# a: Semi-major axis = 6_378_137.0  metres
A = 6_378_137.0
# b: Semi-minor axis ≈ 6_356_752.314_245    metres
B = 6_356_752.314_245
# f = flattening (a−b)/a
F = 1 - B/A
# (a²−b²)/b² ( lat reduction )
F2 = (A / B)**2 - 1

TWO_PI = 2 * np.pi


def get_upsilon2(u2: float) -> tuple[float, float]:
    # u² = cos² α · (a²−b²)/b²
    return (
        # A = 1 + u²/16384 · {4096 + u² · [−768 + u² · (320 − 175 · u²)]}
        1 + u2/16384 * (4096 + u2 * (-768 + u2 * (320 - 175*u2))),
        # B = u²/1024 · {256 + u² · [−128 + u² · (74 − 47 · u²)]}
        u2/1024 * (256 + u2 * (-128 + u2 * (74 - 47*u2))),
    )


def sigma_iteration(sigma_0: np.ndarray, sigma1, alpha, beta, distance) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    # cos 2σm = cos(2σ1 + σ)
    cos_2sigma_m = np.cos(2 * sigma1 + sigma_0)
    # Δσ = B · sin σ · {cos 2σm + B/4 · [cos σ · (−1 + 2 · cos² 2σm)
    # − B/6 · cos 2σm · (−3 + 4 · sin² σ) · (−3 + 4 · cos² 2σm)]}
    delta_sigma = (
        # B · sin σ ·
        beta * np.sin(sigma_0) *
        # cos 2σm + B/4 ·
        (
            cos_2sigma_m + beta/4 *
            # [cos σ ·
            np.cos(sigma_0) *
            (
                #  (−1 + 2 · cos² 2σm) -
                -1 + 2*cos_2sigma_m**2 -
                #   − B/6 · cos 2σm ·
                beta/6 * cos_2sigma_m *
                # (−3 + 4 · sin² σ) ·
                (-3 + 4*np.sin(sigma_0)**2) *
                # (−3 + 4 · cos² 2σm)]
                (-3 + 4*cos_2sigma_m**2)
            )
        )
    )
    # σʹ = s / b·A + Δσ
    sigma = distance/B/alpha + delta_sigma
    return sigma, cos_2sigma_m


def get_sigma(distance: np.ndarray, alpha: float, beta: float, sigma1: float) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    # σ = s / (b·A) (first approximation)
    sigma = distance / B / alpha

    # iterate until change in σ is negligible (e.g. 10-12 ≈ 0.006mm)
    while True:
        old_sigma = sigma
        sigma, cos_2sigma_m = sigma_iteration(old_sigma, sigma1, alpha, beta, distance)
        if np.all(np.abs(old_sigma/sigma - 1) <= 1e-12):
            return sigma, cos_2sigma_m


def get_omega(
    azimuth: float, sigma: np.ndarray, cos_u1: float,
    sin_alpha: float, cos_2sigma_m: np.ndarray, cos2_alpha: float,
) -> np.ndarray:
    # λ = atan(sin σ · sin α1 / cos U1 · cos σ − sin U1 · sin σ · cos α1)
    lambda_ = np.arctan2(
        (np.sin(sigma) * np.sin(azimuth)),
        (np.cos(cos_u1) * np.cos(sigma) - np.sin(cos_u1) * np.sin(sigma) * np.cos(azimuth))
    )
    # C = f/16 · cos² α · [4 + f · (4 − 3 · cos² α)]
    c_sigma = (
        F/16 * cos2_alpha *
        (4 + F*(4 - 3*cos2_alpha))
    )
    # L = λ − (1−C) · f · sin α · {σ + C · sin σ · [cos 2σm + C · cos σ · (−1 + 2 · cos² 2σm)]}
    return (
        lambda_ - (1 - c_sigma)*F*sin_alpha * (
            sigma + c_sigma * np.sin(sigma) * (
                    cos_2sigma_m + c_sigma *
                    np.cos(sigma) * (-1 + 2 * cos_2sigma_m**2)
            )
        )
    )


def get_latitude(azimuth: float, sigma: np.ndarray, cos_u1: float, sin_alpha: float) -> np.ndarray:
    # φ2 = atan(sin U1 · cos σ + cos U1 · sin σ · cos α1 /
    latitude = np.arctan2(
        (np.sin(cos_u1) * np.cos(sigma) + np.cos(cos_u1) * np.sin(sigma) * np.cos(azimuth)),
        # (1−f) · √sin² α + (sin U1 · sin σ − cos U1 · cos σ · cos α1)² )
        (
            (1 - F) * np.sqrt(
                sin_alpha**2 +
                (
                    np.sin(cos_u1) * np.sin(sigma) - np.cos(cos_u1) * np.cos(sigma) * np.cos(azimuth)
                )**2
            )
        )
    )
    return latitude


def vincenty_direct(
    latitude: float,
    longitude: float,
    azimuth: float,
    distance: np.ndarray,
) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    """
    Returns: lat and long of projected point
    """

    # Not necessary:
    azimuth = np.mod(azimuth, TWO_PI)

    # tan U1 = (1−f) · tan φ1
    tan_u1 = (1 - F) * np.tan(latitude)
    # cos U1 = 1 / √1 + tan² U1, sin U1 = tan U1 · cos U1
    cos_u1 = np.arctan(tan_u1)
    # σ1 = atan(tan U1 / cos α1)
    sigma1 = np.arctan2(tan_u1, np.cos(azimuth))
    # sin α = cos U1 · sin α1
    sin_alpha = np.cos(cos_u1) * np.sin(azimuth)
    # cos² α = 1 − sin² α
    cos2_alpha = 1 - sin_alpha**2

    alpha, beta = get_upsilon2(cos2_alpha * F2)
    sigma, cos_2sigma_m = get_sigma(distance, alpha, beta, sigma1)
    latitude = get_latitude(azimuth, sigma, cos_u1, sin_alpha)
    omega = get_omega(azimuth, sigma, cos_u1, sin_alpha, cos_2sigma_m, cos2_alpha)

    return latitude, longitude + omega


def dev_dist(project_seconds=None) -> None:
    if project_seconds is None:
        project_seconds = np.linspace(900, 3600, 4)

    # position
    latitude = 33.01
    longitude = -98.94
    # direction
    azimuth = -171.95
    # speed
    meters_per_second = 11
    # distance projection
    distance = meters_per_second * project_seconds
    # in rads
    rad_lat, rad_lon, rad_azi = np.deg2rad((latitude, longitude, azimuth))

    degs = np.rad2deg(
        vincenty_direct(rad_lat, rad_lon, rad_azi, distance)
    )

    points = degs.T

    assert np.allclose(
        points,
        (
            (32.921612216500890, -98.95482179485320),
            (32.833221427146340, -98.96961414990395),
            (32.744827642960495, -98.98437722206711),
            (32.656430874926910, -98.99911116737137),
        ),
        atol=1e-12, rtol=0,
    )

    times = (f"+{x:02.0f}min" for x in project_seconds / 60)

    projection = dict(zip(times, points.tolist()))
    pprint(projection)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dev_dist()
```

### Output

```
{'+15min': [32.92161221650089, -98.9548217948532],
 '+30min': [32.83322142714634, -98.96961414990395],
 '+45min': [32.744827642960495, -98.98437722206711],
 '+60min': [32.65643087492691, -98.99911116737137]}
```

Comment: Another excellent answer, thank you.

Comment: Was this a typo ’# σʹ = s / b·A + Δσ
    sigma = distance/B/alpha + delta_sigma’

Comment: Should be B*alpha

Comment: Depends. `s / b·A`, the way it's formatted, looks to (incorrectly) assume `s / (bA)` but that's not how order of operations works. If it is indeed s / (bA), then s/b/A is correct. If it is literally s / b * A, then your original implementation is incorrect.